# How to create two-level list dropdown component in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with two layers, like an ExpandableListView inside a dropdown, such that when you click on a child view, you do something.

Something like this:

[image]

How would be the best way to do this? I have not found anything similar online. I have searched for keywords such as "multilevel spinner" or "expandableListView inside dropdown" but could not find anything.

Comment: I don't believe a spinner would be the right widget regardless if you want to achieve something like this. You are better off opening a custom dialog of some sort with a expandableListView inside it as you said.

Comment: Hmm I might just end up doing that, I just wanted to know if this was possible/doable. It's just strange to me that this is not a common thing, perhaps because there would be little space?